# list assignment index out of range when I want to define an array

Tags: python, arrays

that works and when I add this part:

```
print('x-coord',x_coord[0])

force_line = []
force_line[0] = x_coord[0]
force_line[1] = y_coord[0]
force_line[2] = 0
```

I have an error:

```
x-coord -0.5634698919774295
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "centre_motion.py", line 145, in <module>
    force_line[0] = x_coord[0]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

What is wrong, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
force_line = []
```

This creates an empty list with no valid indices. Assigning directly to indices won't work because they're not valid. You can append items to the end of the list with `append()`:

```
force_line.append(x_coord[0])
force_line.append(y_coord[0])
force_line.append(0)
```

Or better yet, construct the list from the start with all of the desired elements:

```
force_line = [x_coord[0], y_coord[0], 0]
```